# 'Table' object has no attribute 'purge' error

Tags: python-3.x

I run this basic code snippets from the TinyDB package manual:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
db = TinyDB('db.json')
db.purge()
db.insert({'type': 'apple', 'count': 7})
print(db.all())
```

with db.purge() in the code i get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users[...].py", line 4, in <module>
    db.purge()

  File "C:\Users[...].py", line 250, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.table(self.default_table_name), name)
    
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'purge'
```

What am I totally missing here?
Using snippets from this manual on page 5  [manualpage](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/v3.2.3/pdf/)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a very old manual here.
Here a newer one:
[new manual TinyDB](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#basic-usage)

It seems they changed `db.purge()` to `db.truncate()`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query 

db = TinyDB('db.json')
db.truncate()
db.insert({'type': 'apple', 'count': 7})
print(db.all())
```

Error is due to version updates
like
db.purge_tables() => db.purge() => db.truncate()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.